# Book a flight from CDG Airport

Tags: air-travel, france, cdg

I am travelling from NYC to Paris, and returning back. If I miss my return flight to NYC, how can I book a new return flight from CDG airport?

I do not speak French, or have a laptop to reserve online.

Does some Air France counter accept cash ?

Comment: The check-in counter can accept cash or credit cards, and they'll even have someone who speaks English!

Comment: You seem very worried about contingencies in case you miss your flight. Is there a reason you think you're so likely to miss your flights?

Comment: @ZachLipton first-time visit to paris, unknown city, inexperienced traveller

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely possible to buy a ticket at the airport, you'd have good chances of being able to find one relatively fast as Paris-NYC is a very frequently serviced route.

CDG being a big international airport, one of the busiest in Europe, you'll have no trouble finding an English speaker, if not Air France then surely an American airline. Counters will accept cash, but you'd probably need a few thousand euros at least to cover a last minute ticket like that.

Be aware that if you miss your flight, you're not entitled to anything from the airline (accommodation, rebooking) unless the flight was delayed or cancelled because of them.

Comment: You're not entitled to anything form the airline, but I would certainly ask the airline to see what they can do before I offered to buy a brand new last-minute ticket. Many airlines (especially non-budget airlines) have internal "flat tire rule" policies where they'll accommodate you if you show up at the airport too late to catch your flight. And you can call the airline if you know you won't be able to make it. Even if you wind up paying, you're still better off if you don't have to forfeit the value of your original ticket and buy a new expensive one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will easily find tickets from Paris to NYC, even on last minute. They might not be really cheap but you'll find some. Here are the companies offering direct flights from Paris to NYC :

- American Airlines
- Air France
- Open Skies (from Orly)
- La Compagnie (full Business class)
- United

And yes you can pay your tickets with cash. Just be aware that if the ticket is too expensive (more than few thousands euros), they might deny cash.

Another point, if you are transiting via Paris and you miss your connection due to delays in your flight to CDG, you are potentially entitled for an hotel room and a new ticket to NYC. There are some terms applying but keep this in mind in case of problems.

Comment: (+1) In France, it's actually illegal to buy something worth more than €1000 from a business in cash if you are a French resident (for foreign residents, the limit is €15000).